# How to monitorJVM and Applications using SNMP

Tags: java, networking, jvm, monitoring, snmp

I understand that JVMs can be managed using SNMP and JVMs come with support for JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB.

Is there a way to program/extend the SNMP AGENT functionality which is associated with a JVM?

Is there a way to add support for any other proprietary/standard MIBs to the SNMP Agent on JVM, so that I can allow my applications running on the JVM to be monitered by external management applications with out making use of a third-party SNMP Agent library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/what_is_the_jvm_snmp, “The built-in SNMP agent of the JVM is not extensible.” It looks to me like you would have to use something like SNMP4J or Sun’s Java™ Dynamic Management Kit.